# Data from MQTT to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mqtt

I have a MQTT publisher running as windows service, which reads from modbus devices and publishes as JSON. The windows service also stores data in a SQL Server database.

I want live graphical representation of the data in ASP.NET MVC. I have written client code to subscribe which receives data when published from windows service but view is not getting refreshed when data is received. I am new to ASP.NET MVC though fairly adept in C#.

I don't want to show data from the database. The code snippet is as below. To test I am just passing single value and show it in view. I used MQTT Lens to publish data and the message is received by the client in controller

```
    public ActionResult DBData()
    {
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("localhost", 1883, false, null, null, 0, null, null);
        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.Connect(clientId);
        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "/gateway/data/1" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });
                                
        return View();
    }

    void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        recdmsg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        ViewBag.Chart = recdmsg;
        RedirectToAction("DBData", "DashBoardDataController");
    }
}
```

The view markup:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DBData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>DBData</h2>
<p>@ViewBag.Chart</p>
```

How to refresh the view whenever subscribed data is received?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the edit and showing the correct way to post.